# How to access sensors not listed by SensorManager?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-sensors, hal, undocumented-behavior

Some devices have a pressure-sensitive virtual home button, that is considered a pressure sensor, not a button. As far as I know these Samsung Galaxy devices are affected: [S8](https://www.theverge.com/2017/3/29/15105330/samsung-galaxy-s8-home-button-virtual-vs-hardware), [S8+](https://news.samsung.com/global/in-depth-look-whats-inside-the-galaxy-s8-and-s8), S9, S9+, [Note10, Note10+ and Fold](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/pressure-sensor/).

[image: Screenshot of Samsung Galaxy S9 and S9+ specs on https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-s9/specs/. Sensors: Iris, Fingerprint, HR, Pressure (!), Gyro, Proximity, Accelerometer, Geomagnetic, RGB Light, Barometer, Hall sensor. Buttons: On/Off, Volume, Bixby. (Home key is not on the list.)]

Since it is a sensor, it should be listed by `SensorManager`:

```
for (Sensor s : ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE)).getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL))
        Log.d("Sensor", s.getName());
```

But it wasn't when I was testing on such a device. How else could it be accessed? I don't know enough about [HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer)](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hal-types). I don't know if [drivers of the Linux kernel](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture) can be used directly. Or is there an undocumented way to access the pressure-sensitive virtual home button?

Comment: This might be relevant: [Android sensors hardware abstraction layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704591/android-sensors-hardware-abstraction-layer).

Comment: This might be even more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073856/1293492